# HW-477 Module having VS1838B IR Sensor: Help with Pins

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, ir

Ordered **Universal IR Receiver** and I got **HW-477 module** with **VS1838B IR Sensor**.

Good thing is datasheet for **VS1838B** is [available](https://www.makerfabs.com/infrared-receiver-vs1838b.html) but not for HW-477.

**VS1838B** pins as: [Ref](https://circuits-diy.com/how-to-make-ir-infrared-reciever-module-using-vs1838b/)
Signal | GND | VCC

while **HW-477** says:
(- minus) | R | G

Can't understand which one to follow and **R** is for Receiver? **G** is for GND and what is **-** (minus sign) for?

So can anyone help me with ( - R G ) of **HW-477** ?

Images:
[image: HW-477 module]
[image: VS1838B IR Sensor.]

These may help?!
[this](https://youtu.be/zwPBItsFBFk?t=255) & [this](https://youtu.be/GnvHHZTJmv4?t=5) one.

**Updates:**

I looked to trace the Foil *(PCB Board Lines)* but it didn't worked because the circuit as whole is coated.

Using **Connectivity** *(Continuity (diode test))* option of Digital Multimeter, found these to play beep:

| **VS1838B** | **HW-477** |
| --- | --- |
| Signal | G & (minus pin of HW-477) |
| GND | (- minus pin of HW-477) |
| VCC | R |

But a person in [this video](https://youtu.be/zwPBItsFBFk?t=255) saying

> - is of course GND

There is a huge confusion which can only be cleared if I got a reply from seniors. I have two of this and can try one (even to burn) to better understand what is going on.

(Tried contacting the vendor about datasheet but they are not responding)

Comment: The only problem I am having is: If I press one button one single time it gives, let suppose this value: `Code: 1086138583` but holding it for a second it gives another value of `Code: 4294967295` which I don't know is a feature or fault. lol

Comment: That's how IR works. The first code is "You pressed the button" and the second is "You're still pressing the button". Not all buttons do it, but things like volume control do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that **HW-477** refers not to the module as a whole but a generic PCB that is re-used (in some starter kits for sure) for many different sensors. I think the idea is that whatever device is attached to the board there's a position where the output is always the same (`- = GND`, `R = VCC`, `G = Signal`).
On some variants of the board you can see them labelled as `- + S`.

Comment: Thank You Sir! It worked. Just a note `IRremote` library from Arduino by `Armin Joachimsmeyer` latest version `3.4.0` didn't worked with legacy code found all over web, so I had to install 2.6.0 version and everything is fine now. Just a note so someone will get benefited.